# PowerApps - out of office on behalf on another user

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm working on the out of office template on PowerApps, but I need to do only one thing to make it more efficient.


The app gets the data of the logged on user, however we  need to make it work for helpdesk team to make them able to activate the autoreply on behalf on any other user in the company.


Your help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Ahmed

Comment: I think you need to authenticate as the user whose out of office message you want to set.  I've created a PowerApp that does that, but it runs with the credentials of the user. For security purposes and other reasons, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: The problem is we previously were working on exchange server 2008 and just migrated to O365, we were using a script launcher with GUI for helpdesk to use.
Now we needed another solution that work for helpdesk mainly and for users optionally, not sure if powerapps would fulfill this request, if you have any other solutions fill me in please.

Comment: How does the Helpdesk learn which user is out of office? THAT is the process you need to change. Instead of the user notifying the helpdesk, the user can run a PowerApp on their phone or in the browser, click a few buttons and, hey presto, Out of Office all done. I know because I have written such apps.

Comment: I already created a powerapp for users to use, but there's some cases using powerapp wouldn't be able to be used, like user exit and user sick leave, when we had such a case the manager would send to helpdesk to set the autoreply, we can't accomplish this right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set an OoO (Out of Office) message, you must be logged in with the credentials of that user.

If the user has left the company, IT can take ownership of the account, log in with the expired user's credentials and set the Out of Office message. Something like this should not happen too often, so automating such a rare event is probably more effort than doing it manually for ten years.

If the user is sick, they can call in sick through the app, and the app sets the OoO message with the user's credentials. I've built such apps and they are very popular, because people can use them on the phone. Instead of calling in to work and tell someone they're sick, they just use the app to hit 5 buttons and can go back to sleep.